# Cannot find template in Java web script in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, web-scripting

I have followed this tutorial to create a send email custom action using Java backed Webscript:
http://ecmstuff.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-document-library-actions-in.html?showComment=1403279845779#c303784066266925848

As has been mentioned above, there is an AbstractWebScript class defined just to execute the action without using a freemaker template, but I get this error:
Cannot locate template processor for template sendDocInEmail.get.html

I guess, there is a problem with the -context.xml file

My files are placed in the following folders:
1. the java .class files are in \tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes (placed with the package structure)
2. sendDocInEmail.get.desc in \tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts folder (with the package structure)
3. services-context.xml file in the folder \tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module (again with the package structure)

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely derived your class from `DeclarativeWebScript` which extends `AbstractWebScript` and adds the template processing. Make sure to derive your class from the latter.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I have derived my class from the AbstractWebScript class. But still there is an error.

Comment: Looks like your code does not kick in at all. Make sure your bean definition has parent webscript and id webscript.sendDocInEmail.get. Make sure it is picked up. If in doubt, place it in classes/alfresco/extension/for-context.xml.